# ¿Cómo convertir una oración encerrada en asteriscos en strong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una cadena de texto como esta:

> Aliquam sit amet * scelerisque odio *, at ullamcorper justo. Phasellus
> at sem ultricies, gravida lorem id, faucibus tellus.

Lo que quiero es que la oración que esté encerrada entre asteriscos se convierta strong. He intentado esto, pero no funciona:

```
var value = $('.articulo').val();
var regex = /\*([a-zA-Z\d\w\s]+)\*/gi
$(".articulo").html(value.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>"));
```

Agradezco sus respuestas y comentarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto pasa debido a que los elementos de texto, digamos una etiqueta "p" de html no cuenta con la propiedad "value", para obtener el contenido de una elemento de "p" dentro del DOM tienes que usar el método $('.articulo').html() o $('.articulo').text();

El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("articulo");
var value = element.textContent || "";
var regex = /\*([a-zA-Z\d\w\s]+)\*/gi;
element.innerHTML = value.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>");
```

```html
<p id="articulo">Aliquam sit amet * scelerisque odio *, at ullamcorper justo. Phasellus at sem ultricies, gravida lorem id, faucibus tellus.</p>
```

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por tu respuesta. Lamentablemente no me funcionó de la manera que indicas, de hecho no hace absolutamente nada, no muestra resultados ni siquiera de error en la consola.

Comment: Podrias agregar tu código HTML a la pregunta ? eso ayudaria a ver a mas detalle la problematica

Comment: @Samsepi de hecho acabo de probar el código y hace lo que pides, como te dicen, lo mejor sería editar tu  pregunta agregando más detalles. Saludos.